# Firebase performance automatic traces are not working with android eclipse project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

We are trying to implement firebase performance with an old eclipse android project. we implemented other features like analytics, remote config with this project with firebase 11.8.0.

But when coming to performance the automatic traces are not working but manual traces are working. our application is not dexGuarded.

Can any one have any clue about the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must build your project with Gradle using the Performance Monitoring plugin to get automatic traces.  The plugin performs bytecode manipulation at build time.  It doesn't support Eclipse.